# Явное преобразование неизвестных типов для размера вектора

Tags: c++, типы

У меня есть количество элементов `type_1 n` и размер каждого элемента `type_2 size`. Я хочу создать вектор размера `n * size`. Типы `type_1` и `type_2` неизвестные шаблонные. Надо ли делать какие-то явные преобразования типов/проверки  или достаточно написать `n * size`?

Тип элемента вектора роли не играет, он фиксирован и не зависит от `n` и `size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
#include <limits>

...
type_1 n = ...;
type_2 size = ...;
typedef std::vector<some_type>::size_type size_type;

if (std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / size >= n)
{
    std::vector<some_type> vect(size_type(size) * n); //Помним, что здесь всё ещё может быть сгенерировано исключение
    ...
}
```

Условие `std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / size >= n` гарантирует, что  результат произведения `size_type(size) * n` представим типом `std::vector<some_type>::size_type` точно, без всяких модулярных арифметик и неопределённых поведений. Следовательно, его можно спокойно передавать в методы вектора, не опасаясь усечения.

Тем не менее, это ещё не значит, что вектор заданного размера будет успешно сконструирован:

1. Нельзя сконструировать вектор, количество элементов которого больше, чем значение, возвращаемое методом [`max_size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size),
2. При конструировании вектора размером меньше, чем `max_size()`, всё ещё есть ненулевой шанс, что просто-напросто не хватит памяти.

Comment: а я сильно не уверен, что условие `std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / size >= n` определяет максимальное кол-во элементов, которое вместится в вектор.  Более того, сорцы stl с gcc подтвержают это https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h

Comment: @KoVadim, а оно и не определяет кол-во элементов, которое можно вместить в вектор. Это условие проверяет отсутствие переполнения при вычислении произведения.

Answer (score 0):

Это же вектор, он сам размер элемента посчитает и его сразу можно попросить выделить достаточно памяти.

```
template<typename T>
void foo(size_t size)
{
    std::vector<T> v(size); // это будет вектор нужного типа и уже нужного размера
    // можно пользоваться вектором  v
}

int main()
{
    foo<int>(100);//зададим тип и желаемый размер
}
```

**upd**

попытка угадать желание

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T, typename N>
void foo(N size)
{
    // проверим, что тип беззнаковый
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned<N>::value, "unsigned type only");
    std::vector<T> v;
    // проверим, что оно влезет
    assert(v.max_size() > size);
    // создадим вектор нужного размера
    v.resize(size);
}
```

и теперь вот так

```
foo<int>(100u);
```

будет работать, а вот так

```
foo<int>(100);
```

уже нет.

Comment: Не понял, в вашем примере уже известный тип и только 1 параметр. У меня же 2 параметра неизвестных (возможно, разных) типов, произведение которых будет размером вектора

Comment: Вы не можете создать объект, размер которого  неизвестен. Если Вам неизвестен тип, то создать этот объект никак нельзя. Результирующий тип все равно будет известен. То, что Вам известен размер этого элемента, ничего не меняет, все равно можно его узнать через sizeof(type_1)

Comment: Размер математический известен `n * size` (при 5 и 2 = 10), типы внутри функции известные, но шаблонные, поэтому могут при преобразованиях выдать что-то плохое. Тут вопрос как правильно вычислить тип размера и произведение без переполнений и прочего, тип элемента вектора фиксирован и не зависит от `n` и `size`

Comment: если результирующий размер будет с переполнением, то тут уже проблема. Но если есть подозрения, что некоторые типы "плохие", тогда sfinae / if constexpr поможет. Но в этом случае вопрос сформулирован не очень четко.

Comment: Вопрос в том, как эту проблему решить. Проверить, что тип беззнаковый можно, например. Но даже тогда, если оба типа маленькие, то произведение может не поместиться. Добавил уточнение в вопрос, раз есть недопонимание

Comment: уточнение немного слабое. размер элемента всегда беззнаковый, но можно использовать https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned . А переполнение можно проверить - добавляю в ответ